# Action_Move Android issue

Tags: java, android

I have been working on a game for a while, and I am working on the controls right now, and I am hitting an issue with the Action_Move. My code is set up as shown below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
            {
                if(event.getPointerId(i) == 0 && primDown)
                {
                    x = (int) event.getX();
                    y = (int) event.getY();
                }
                else if(event.getPointerId(i) == 1 && secDown)
                {
                    x1 = (int) event.getX(1);
                    y1 = (int) event.getY(1);
                    if(dirPadRight.contains(x1, y1))
                    {
                        Log.w("game", "Right " + x1 +" " + y1);
                    }
                    if(dirPadLeft.contains(x1, y1))
                    {
                        Log.w("game", "Left " + x1 +" " + y1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The primDown and secDown booleans are set up in the switch statement below:

```
int index = event.getAction() >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                if(pointerId == 0)
                {
                    primDown = true;
                }
                else if(pointerId == 1)
                {
                    secDown = true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                if(pointerId == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    primDown = false;
                }
                else if(pointerId == 1)
                {
                    x1 = 0;
                    y1 = 0;
                    secDown = false;
                }                      
                break;
            }
```

Basically, I am just having it refresh the x, y, x1, and y1 any time any action happens, so that I don't have to deal with ACTION_MOVE in the switch statement, but when I try moving with the secondary pointer, it doesn't change the event.getX(1) or event.getY(1). AS you can see, I put the log statements into the second pointer part of my for loop, and they go off whether I have both the primary pointer down and the secondary down, or if I had lifted the primary pointer and just the secondary is down, but it isn't changing the x1 or y1, it keeps outputting the original points.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working for me? It is weird that it knows a movement is happening, but it just isn't changing the x and y's, so I figured someone would know here. Let me know if you need any more code. Thanks in advance!

WWaldo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
if(pointerId == 0)
                {
                    primDown = true;
                    secDown=false;
                }
                else if(pointerId == 1)
                {
                    secDown = true;
                    primDown=false;
                }
```

This is difficult to say what causing your problem without seeing all the code.May be you are messing up with the boolean variable so that whenever a code should work it is not working.

Comment: I just tried this, sadly it didn't work. I am not really sure what else I can post code wise, nothing else uses anything in here yet. When ACTION_MOVE happens, do you get the new point with event.getX() just like you would any other way? I guess that could be the issue, but it works for the primary pointer, which is why I am confused.

Comment: case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:You didn't write any thing for this case.If switch matches with it what will happen.As i know switch statement executes all the rest cases if it is not break after a match regardless of the cases next

Comment: The way that one is set up its like an if statement with an or, if either of those happen, it executes the code below it